# Why does a badge progress bar keep incrementing after getting the badge?

Tags: support, badges

On image hover on the review page I get something like this:

[image]

As you can see, the Civic Duty badge is already completed but it's showing **407**. I think after **300** it should have stopped the progress bar. Could anyone explain this to me? Why after being completed is the progress bar still incremented?

Comment: Why not? Does it really matter?

Comment: After 500 your monitor will explode...

Comment: What does the increment means? Is it the votes or review count?

Comment: What happens when it's over 9000?

Comment: For the Civic Duty badge, it's the number of times you voted.

Answer (score 7):

There's no further badges to be awarded in this subject, so the progress bar ought to show 100% completion. To then freeze the review count at 300 would be a falsehood and would be followed up by lots of meta questions "*Why doesn't it show the real number? I'd like to know!*".

Comment: I can imagine that question being asked. So, the lesson is: It doesn't matter what you do; you will be always questioned. `:)`